# Accessing Toast within Composable Functions Across Different Files in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable function `MainScreen` that calls another composable function `MainActionBar`. The two functions are in different files.

```
@Composable
fun MainActionBar(
    onAddButton: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
        contentDescription = "Add Icon",
        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
            .clickable { onAddButton() }
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, when I call `MainActionBar` from the screen, I cannot get the Toast.

```
@Composeable
fun MainScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    MainActionBar(
        onAddButton = {
            Toast
                .makeText(context, "On Development", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    )
}
```

Is it because of the context that I generate?
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What error message do you get? Have you verified that it really works if you move both functions into the same file? Your question implies the problem only occurs when they are in different files.